# How to parse response from a server to node.js request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, request

I am using node js request module to request a html of an url input. I am able to get the hrml successfully with the following.

```
request(build[i], function(error, response, html)
```

but unable to parse response and access the data inside. This is the response from the server.

```
 <ref *2> IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: true,
    ended: true,
    endEmitted: true,
    reading: false,
    constructed: true,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: false,
    dataEmitted: true,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
  },
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function (anonymous)] ],
    close: [ [Function (anonymous)], [Function (anonymous)] ],
    data: [Function (anonymous)],
    error: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: <ref *1> TLSSocket {
    _tlsOptions: {
      allowHalfOpen: undefined,
      pipe: false,
      secureContext: [SecureContext],
      isServer: false,
      requestCert: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      session: undefined,
      ALPNProtocols: undefined,
      requestOCSP: undefined,
      enableTrace: undefined,
      pskCallback: undefined,
      highWaterMark: undefined,
      onread: undefined,
      signal: undefined
    },
    _secureEstablished: true,
    _securePending: false,
    _newSessionPending: false,
    _controlReleased: true,
    secureConnecting: false,
    _SNICallback: null,
    servername: 'mysterioustrip.com',
    alpnProtocol: false,
    authorized: true,
    authorizationError: null,
    encrypted: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      close: [Array],
      end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
      newListener: [Function: keylogNewListener],
      secure: [Function: onConnectSecure],
      session: [Function (anonymous)],
      free: [Function: onFree],
      timeout: [Function: onTimeout],
      agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
      error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
      finish: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 10,
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: 'mysterioustrip.com',
    _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      constructed: true,
```

i tried accessing the key value inside the response object through . notation, but it did not work.How do i get access to it.

Comment: "I am using node js request module" — Stop! [Read the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). It was deprecated two and a half years ago.

Comment: "i tried accessing the key value inside the response object through . notation" — Please read [ask]. Don't vaguely describe your code. Provide a [mcve].